# Socket.io global sending Function - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I build a simple node.js / socket.io app.
I need for emitting events a module, that can be accessible through other modules so I can send socket messages when there is for example a new database entry.

Something like this:

```js
function sendWebsocketEvent (whereToSend, EventName, Payload) {
    io.in(whereToSend).emit(EventName, Payload)
  }
```

How can I handle that?

I've tried that:

-- app.js --

```js
// Websockets
var http = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http)
http.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on Port *:3000')
})
require('./WebSockets/socketInit')(io)
```

-- socketInit.js --

```js
module.exports = (ioInput) => {
  const io = ioInput
  return io
}
```

-- sendSockets.js --

```js
const io = require('./socketInit')
module.exports = {
  sendWebsocketEvent (whereToSend, EventName, Payload) {
    io.in(whereToSend).emit(EventName, Payload)
  }
}
```

And I tried to call this function at another module:

```js
const sendSockets = require('../WebSockets/sendSockets')
.
.
.
 sendSockets.sendWebsocketEvent('user', 'databaseUpdate', 'dataToSend')
 .
 .
 .
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there an other way for getting this done?

- Chris

Comment: Please refer my recently added article on socket.io, this could help you: https://github.com/sarveshmahajan89/My-Chat-App

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside `Server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = socket.listen(server);
global.io = io;

const port = process.env.PORT || 5500;
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`%s  Server is listening on port ${port}`, chalk.green('✓')));

// socket io connection 
let interval;
io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("New client connected");
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

And emit where you want just like that

```
global.io.emit('EventName', data);
```